# Preferred way of persisting timestamps for platform-neutral consumption

Tags: java, timezone, timestamp, jpa-2.0, jodatime

So, basically I have a JPA + Spring Data + Hibernate application in which I store a date & time objects.

Imagine we have the following scenario:

> That this is a server storing 'check-in' data - like a location
>   repository for a check-in service i.e. Foursquare.
>
> And data from this repository service is used in a REST API which in turn is
>   consumed by Android/iOS/etc clients.
>
> Now, for every check-in besides the latitude/longitude, userId and etc, I have a timestamp when the check-in was made.

How should I store this timestamp? Should I have a java.util.Date object or a Joda Time object? Should I keep the timezone data or remove it from the timestamp before persisting and use another TimeZone field for that?

Comment: Use the Joda library if you can. It's designed much better than java.util.Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that really matters is that when you send the data over the wire that it is serialized in a common format.  The most ubiquitous format these days is [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601).

Since this is a check-in at a particular location, the most appropriate form would be a local date/time with an offset.  In ISO8601 format, it would look like:

```
2012-12-01T12:34:56-0700
```

I am not a Java programmer, but I believe the JodaTime `DateTime` has the most correct implementation for this.

Comment: Thanks for the ISO suggestion, I'll try that way.